# Reading multiple files to multiple arraylists

Tags: java, io

i have 5 text files that i am trying to read each of them into a single array lists so 5 files need 5 array lists to be stored in.

i write a code that success in storing all five text files into only one array list. 
i found that the while loop is executed only once in the first scenario so the problem is in the while loop and how it executed but unfortunately i could not figure out the problem exactly.
my code here is accessing the directory where my files is , then i list these files and stored them into a file array.
in the first for loop i concatenate the directory path with the file name
in the second loop i am reading the contents of the file.

as i mentioned earlier the whole problem is with while loop, thats what i figure out.

Here is my code:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> readFromFile() throws IOException
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        String s =null; 
        File file = new File("/home/abed/Downloads/practical_database_java-StudentVers/practical_database_java/Database/Oracle") ;
        String []files = file.list();
        String [] filestoberead = new String[files.length];

        for(int i = 0 ;i<files.length;i++)
        {
            filestoberead[i] = file+"/"+files[i] ;
            System.out.println(filestoberead[i]);
        }

        for(int j =0;j<filestoberead.length;j++)
        {
            try(BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filestoberead[j])))
            {
                reader.readLine();
                while((s=reader.readLine())!=null)
                {

                    data.get(j).add(s);
                }
            }
        }




        return data  ; 
    }
```

Comment: [java.nio.file.Files#readAllLines(Path)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the list before You use it:

```
data.add(new ArrayList<String>());
try(BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filestoberead[j])))
{
    reader.readLine();
    while((s=reader.readLine())!=null)
    {
        data.get(j).add(s);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

And, BTW, you could simplify the creation of `filestoberead`:

```
    File dir = new File("/home/abed/Downloads/practical_database_java-StudentVers/practical_database_java/Database/Oracle") ;
    File[] filestoberead = dir.listFiles();
```

Comment: this one need an consumer , actually i prefer to use NIO.2 API but the reason that make me use File is that i could not list only regular files name without its directories

Answer (score 0):

In deed you have an error into your while and you have an extra reader.readLine();

try this:

```
 try(BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filestoberead[j])))
            {
                ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
                while((s=reader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    tmp.add(s);
                }
                data.add(tmp)

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also in NIO

```
        try {
            List<List<String>> contents = new ArrayList<>();
            Iterator<Path> it = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("."), "*.*").iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()){
               contents.add(Files.readAllLines(it.next()));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't do what the original does. It turns all files into one single `String`. This is not good at all.

Comment: Still not correct. Come on, there are dozens of ways to do this, and none of them are very hard.

Comment: Just use `Files.readLines()` (and remember to use the correct charset). It returns a `List<String>`. You're trying to do a lot of things that are unnecessary and wrong. There isn't a method called `readAllLines`, it's implied that they're all read.